# iPhone Custom keyboard does not load on physical device running iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, simulator

I've successfully written a custom keyboard for iOS with swift and it loads perfectly on all iOS simulators (iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6Plus). but when I try to test my keyboard on physical device, keyboard won't load. :|

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 and my iPhone runs iOS 8 (not beta version) and I've added my keyboard in Keyboard section in setting.

It's weird that keyboards load perfectly on simulator, but not actual device.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, to test your keyboard on physical device, you have to change the value of the `RequestsOpenAccess` Boolean key in the `Info.plist` file to YES.

and by Info.plist I mean Info.plist for your keyboard extension not containing app.

Then after running application on physical device yo have to grant access to keyboard in keyboard section of general and voila. :)

Comment: Same issue here and yes that is a solution but does it work in a shipped ap without RequestOpenAccess then?

Comment: Yeah, keyboards works, but without that request, you can't configure your keyboard from your containing application.

Comment: My problem is that the keyboard is not even showing up.

Comment: I've built and run a keyboard extension on my phone without setting the RequestsOpenAccess flag to YES, so unless something has changed with Xcode 6.1, this answer is likely wrong.

Comment: @RandyHill Answer is not wrong, actually my question is kinda wrong, more accurate something is wrong with my iPhone. I cannot run any (and by any, I really mean any) keyboard on my iPhone without granting `Allow Full Access`. Even if it's a completely fresh keyboard that I just created on Xcode! It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes I made that caused my keyboard extension to stop loading.

First, I created an app profile that had entitlements that didn't match the project. I ended up just deleting the profile and building with automatic settings since I'm pretty far from testing/submitting.

I also had changed the name of the entry UITextViewController and the extensions storyboard without updating them in the NSExtension principle class in it's info.plist.